# Who scolded whom in Aに怒られる?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I can see that someone got mad or someone made someone else mad. The things that make it difficult are `に` and the `られる` form of `怒る`. What does this mean? How do you figure out who did what in these types of sentences?

Comment: By “the られら form,” do you mean “the られた form”?

Comment: Yes. That just looks like the た form of られる。

Comment: If it is a typo, please fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may first bear mentioning that 怒られる is usually used specifically to mean "got scolded by", rather than "to became the focus of someone's anger".

This may make it easier to understand.

- Aは怒った : A got angry

  AはBに怒った : A got angry at B (in this usage, B is usually not a person, but rather an event or state of affairs).

  AはBを怒った : A scolded B (B is a person)

  BはAに怒られた : B got scolded by A.

Comment: Shouldn't the explanations of the 2nd and 3rd cases be swapped?

Comment: @dainichi nope. Example: 彼は生徒の態度に怒った = he got angry at the student's attitude. 彼は生徒を怒った = he scolded the student.

Comment: Hm... interesting. I wasn't able to find an authoritative answer either way. Let me know if you have one. I hear に怒る used for people all the time, which I guess is what got me confused. Googling, I see both used for both people and events. Googling for the difference, I see some saying it has to do with people versus events, and others saying it has to do with the level of anger.

Comment: The distinction is between scolding someone (を怒る）and getting angered by them (に怒る). So it's not necessarily a mistake to say so-and-soに怒る、it just means they angered you, rather than you scolded them. That said, it does seem more rare to use Xに怒る, rather than specifying something about them that angered you, for example Xのだらしなさに怒る (got upset at X's sloppiness).

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the fact that `に` is used in both active and passive sentences with `怒る` is making it difficult for you. `に` can be used either as a dative case marker or as an element leading the agentive-phrase in passive. In English, you can see that the dative is `to`, whereas the agentive-phrase is headed by `by`, so an active sentence with dative case and its passive counterpart look pretty much different:

> A gave a present to B          (`to` as dative case)
>
> B was given a present by A    (`by` heading an agentive phrase in passive)

But in Japanese, they are both expressed as `に`. So an active sentence with dative case and its passive counterpart may look confusing:

> AがBに怒った     (`に` as dative case)
>
> BがAに怒られた   (`に` heading an agentive phrase in passive)

The two examples above describe (roughly) the same event; in both sentences, A is who scolded, and B is who was scolded. But in the first sentence, it is B that appears with `に`, and in the second sentence, it is A. I think that was where you were confused. But you should be able to distinguish the two sentences by looking at whether the verb is in active or passive form. If you see that it is in active form `怒る`, then the phrase that comes with `に` is **the one who is being scolded**. If it is in passive form `怒られる`, then the phrase that comes with `に` is **the one who is scolding**.

---

**Advanced part**

Language hacker raised an interesting point in the comment, so I will add something. You can also see the difference between the two usages of `に` when you topicalize the relevant phrase. The dative `に` becomes optional in front of `は`, but the agentive `に` is obligatory:

> Aは、Bには怒ったが、Cには怒らなかった     (dative case `に` preceding `は`)
>
> Aは、Bは怒ったが、Cは怒らなかった        (dative case `に` omitted before `は`)
>
> Bは、Aには怒られたが、Dには怒られなかった   (agentive `に` preceding `は`)
>
> * Bは、Aは怒られたが、Dは怒られなかった   (Ungrammatical to omit agentive `に` preceding `は`)
>
> (* indicates ungrammatical sentence.)

Comment: I'm still not confident. Aに怒られた means that A made someone mad, or someone made A mad? Also what happens if you have は、が、and に in the same sentence?

Comment: @language hacker The former. It's passive. What is it that is making it so difficult to you?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine what would happen if は was added to the sentence. e.g. AはBがCに怒った/起こられた

Comment: Also I'm trying to find out what 怒られたくて means. It looks like the たい form combined with the られる form, which doesn't seem to make sense in English. Should I make it a separate questions?

Comment: @sawa @language hacker: No, it's not the former, it's the latter. Aに怒られた means (I) got scolded by A, not that A made (me) mad.

Comment: @SuperElectric No, it is the former. You are comparing wrong things.

Comment: See how confusing it is?

Comment: @language hacker AはBがCに怒った/起こられた is ungrammatical. It does not make sense.

Comment: @language hacker `怒られたくて` is 'want to be scolded'.

Comment: You both seem to know what you're talking about. The other answer seems correct as well. Maybe it's confusing because you switched A and B.

Comment: @Dave Maybe it's cultural difference. The additional part might have been difficult, but for the original part, I put basic English examples to make clear what those terms mean. Turning a dative construction into passive is something that normal students learn in English classes at junior highschool or highschool in Japan, or in many other countries, and is not something special. In this case, it is the key to the answer, and I couldn't think of other ways to explain it. But respectful downvote is not such a bad thing, and I can see that you wanted a different kind of explanation.

Comment: @sawa: I'm not going to downvote you because I feel that would be unfair in light of having written my own answer, but I'm honestly having a hard time seeing the practicality in this answer. (Maybe I should have paid more attention in my high school English and Latin classes. :) Is there any way you can bring this down to a more plebeian level?

Comment: @Derek I modified it a little bit.

Answer (score 8):

This is one of those cases where the Japanese られる doesn't quite line up nicely with the English passive:

> Aが怒った。 A got mad.
>
> （私が）A**に**怒られた。 (I) was gotten mad at **by** A. (More naturally in the active: A got mad at me.)
>
> 雨が降った。 The rain fell.
>
> （私が）雨**に**降られた。 (I) was fallen on **by** the rain. (More naturally: I got rained on.)

With the passive られる, the subject of the sentence (usually 私 if it's omitted) is the "target" (on the receiving end) of the action. In other words, something is done *to* the subject rather than *by* the subject. (The *by* part is marked by に, as sawa mentioned.)

To address your comment about the たい construction, then:

> 彼女に怒られたい I want to be gotten mad at by her. (More naturally in the active: I want her to get mad at me.)

Also, when に is used not with 怒られる, but with 怒る, it marks the cause of anger:

> 環境破壊**に**怒る become angry **over** destruction of the environment
>
> 入場できないこと**に**怒る become angry **over** not being able to enter

Comment: I almost posted this as a separate answer, but then I saw it buried in here.  +1 for making it clear that the passive is easier to understand if you translate is as "<verb> **at/on by** <agent>".

Answer (score 7):

What none of the other answers pointed out is that the `rare` passive construction in Japanese actually has two distinct usages, one of which is only tangentially related to English passives but usually clamped together under that terminology when taught. I was originally taught it as the "sufferer passive" (which sounds better in my native language), I've seen it in Japanese as 迷惑の受け身 and one linguistics presentation I've been to called it an Affected Experiencer Construction. Sometimes, a sentence is ambiguous syntactically between the two usages, sometimes it is not.

Unlike regular passives, which take a transitive verb and move the object so it becomes the subject, the 迷惑の受け身 also works with intransitives and can make sentence patterns you wouldn't find with regular passives even when working with transitives. In general, the constuction means that something was done, and someone was affected by experiencing that action - almost always negatively. That `雨に降られた` example Derek's answer is exactly this construction, but here are some more examples:

> （母は）赤ちゃんに泣かれた。　The baby cried, and that troubled his mother.
>
> パパに死なれた。　Dad died, and that upsets me (a very self-centered thing to say!)
>
> 誰かに足を踏まれた。 Someone stepped on my foot, and I don't like that. Note that 足 gets the object particle even though it would have been the subject if this was a normal passive.
>
> 太郎が花子に花瓶を壊された。　Hanako broke Taro's vase, and that upset him. Again, 花瓶 is not treated as it would have been in a normal passive sentence. Made even more complicated by something like:
>
> 太郎が花子に次郎の花瓶を壊された。　　Hanako broke Jiro's vase, and that didn't please Taro (maybe because he would be blamed for breaking it, or for any other contextually available reason)

(To give credit, the last two sentences are derived from that linguistics presentation I mentioned)

What does all that have to do with 怒られた? I think it can be interpreted as an example of this pattern in addition to the classic passive. Someone was mad and I was in trouble because of that (hence, he was mad at me). In addition, since 怒る is listed in my dictionary as an intransitive verb, this syntactic interpretation makes even more sense to me.

Comment: In those last two sentences, it looks like the performer of the action is 花子, not 太郎 (changing it to 花子 would maintain consistency with your first three sentences). If this is not a typo, please add some explanation for why the performer changes.

Comment: It was indeed a typo, thanks. Just goes to show how confusing this construction can be sometimes.

Comment: パパに死なれた。i think i have heard this translated as
"dad up and died on me".

Answer (score 5):

***Note:** Edited after some consultation with native speakers.*

I feel your pain. These used to confuse the heck out of me for a long time, so I know where you are coming from.

I'm assuming you are in a situation where you're reading something, and context can be spread out over pages. You find a sentence fragment like 「ボブに怒られた」 and you're wondering if someone is angry at Bob, or Bob is angry at someone. The subject was maybe established three pages ago, and you could maybe go back and check, but you want to be able to keep trucking like a native speaker would, sure in your knowledge of which way the action is flowing.

First, for the purpose of sorting this out, think of に in terms of being a pointer. It says that something is going toward the thing that it is connected to. Anger doesn't really move around like a ball, but just imagine it does.

So we have two cases:

> ボブに怒った。
>
> ボブに怒られた。

Both sentences have "Bob" and "anger" in them, but, if your confusion is like mine was, you're not sure which of them means Bob is angry, and which means someone is angry at Bob. Or, at least, how to reliably and systematically determine the difference.

In both cases, に points *at* Bob, so to figure out who is angry, we need to be more precise about what *exactly* is coming *at* him. There's a ball of anger coming at him, the type of ball is different because of the different verb form.

In the first case, ボブに怒った, it's just plain anger coming at Bob. The anger ball is being thrown at his head by someone. He just receives someone's anger. Thus, someone is angry at him.

In the second case, ボブに怒られた, what is coming at Bob is the *potential to be angry*. He is being *endowed* with anger. This time, because of the verb form, the anger ball is absorbed into Bob, so this time it's Bob that is angry. Something or someone *made* him angry.

You can at this point, be sure about the direction of the action, without being thrown by the use of に. However, there is more to the story.

You could also translate ボブに怒られた as "Bob scolded [someone]". It's a fragment, so we don't know who Bob is angry at, but the thing is, Bob has been endowed with anger, and anger as a concept is usually directed at someone or something. So Bob is angry, most likely, at the person who threw the anger ball at him. He has still been endowed with anger, so it's still okay to think of it as "Bob was made angry". It's just that the focus is on Bob, and and his anger is probably going somewhere now that he has it.

What if you want to put the focus on the person who made Bob angry? Then you could do this:

> ボブに怒らせた

This also says "Bob was made angry" or "Bob scolded [someone]" but because of the ~らせる form, the emphasis is on the fact that *someone* (or something) made Bob angry.

Let's say Taro made Bob angry. If we say 太郎がボブに怒らせた, we are saying that Taro is definitely responsible for Bob's anger, even though Taro might not have done anything deliberately. The point is that focus is on Taro's action.

If we say 太郎がボブに怒られた, we're saying Bob got angry at Taro, even though Taro might not have done a thing to deserve it. The focus is on Bob's reaction.

In short, the point is that に always directs action onto something. But when you use られる, or らせる, you are directing an endowment onto the target. The target then takes on that quality instead of just receiving it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you are confusing the passive `られ` and the potential `られ`. They are different things. There is also honorific `られ`. By the way, 'Bob' will be transcribed as `ボブ`, not `ボッブ`.

Comment: I think your third sentence is a little off. Did you mean ボブが怒らせられた。?

Comment: @Dave M G - No, 「ボブに怒らせた」means "*I* made Bob angry".  「ボブが怒らせられた」 means "Bob was made angry", but we don't know by whom.

Comment: @istrasci: Actually, "I made Bob angry" would be ボブ **を** 怒らせた. See 奥華子「変わらないもの」: 「帰り道ふざけて歩いた／訳も無く君を怒らせた」. :)

Comment: @Derek Schaab - is this a nuance of 怒る?  Because I'm pretty sure 使役動詞 can use either 〜に or 〜を (except in the no-two-を's-in-a-row rule).

Comment: @istrasci: I stand corrected: for an intransitive verb like 怒る, both に and を are allowed. Thank you for reminding me of that. :)

Comment: @istrasci: In the absence of context, in 「ボブに怒らせた」 it would be *assumed* that the speaker is the cause. If we said  「彼がボブに怒らせた」 , then we know "he" made Bob angry. However, the original poster is expressing confusion because a lot of times the context can be difficult to extrapolate from. The cause might have been named three pages ago in the manga (or whatever). The OP is looking to understand the targets and directions of cause and effect so as to be less buffeted by context, and so I think what I say still applies, though perhaps I could clarify better in my answer.

Comment: @Questioner: I think your explanation is one of the most helpful I came across when dealing with the passive/potential. Thanks a lot!