# The song 「雪が降る」 by アダモ goes --> ♪♪ 雪は降る あなたは来ない ... ♪♪

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-が, song-lyrics, は-and-が

ADAMO, [Tombe la neige]

The song 「雪が降る」 by アダモ  goes -->  ♪♪   雪は降る あなたは来ない ... ♪♪

1. Is there a good explanation for the difference between the title and how the song begins?  --   雪が vs. 雪は ...
2. Are the following alternative words better or worse?

   ```
   The song starting as -->  ♪♪   雪が降る あなたは来ない ... ♪♪
   ```

Related:  [Use は or が with ある when the phrase doesn't explicit the place](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39180/use-%e3%81%af-or-%e3%81%8c-with-%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b-when-the-phrase-doesnt-explicit-the-place)

One obvious relationship is this :

By applying naruto's excellent summary, the following explanation is possible.

「雪が ... 」 in the title introduces the subject (snow) for the 1st time  (e.g., "a boy"), and when it is mentioned the 2nd time, it should be "the snow"

雪は降る == The snow (that we are talking about) is falling. [thematic]

```
          There could be a new tag [ particle-がvs.は ]
                   -->   Thanks, oals, i just added it.
```

Comment: Actually, I think this question is not really related to [Use は or が with ある when the phrase doesn't explicit the place](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39180/use-%E3%81%AF-or-%E3%81%8C-with-%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-when-the-phrase-doesnt-explicit-the-place)。

Comment: `when it is mentioned the 2nd time, it should be "the snow" 雪は降る == The snow (that we are talking about) is falling. [thematic]` <- The は in 雪は降る here is not D-①[thematic] but D-②[contrastive].

Answer (score 5):

When someone wants to put two things as **comparison** in Japanese, they will say **Aは...Bは...。** So in this song, it will be better to use **は...は...。** I think maybe it can mean - Even the snow is already falling, ***but*** you still do not show up. To emphasize the feeling of disappointment.

Comment: @chocolate "has already fallen"  or "is already falling"?

Comment: @virmaior えっ、どっちでしょう、わかんないです・・ `has already fall` になってたんで、 fall を fallen にしたんです・・

Comment: Thank you both for correcting me. Sorry for poor English. fallenよりfallingの方が相応しいと思います。なので、fallingに直します。

Comment: (私は snow keeps falling とか it keeps snowing って感じだと思いますけどね・・・「雪は降りつづける、でもあなたはいっこうに来ない。。」みたいな。。。)

Comment: It already started to snowはどうですか。多分こういう意味でしょうか。According to the whole song, I finally think show is falling would be better

Comment: ええと、歌詞のあとのほうに、「あなたはこない　いくら呼んでも　雪だけが　ただ　降るばかり」っていうのが出てくるんです。まあ、それで、そういう感じかな、と・・

Answer (score 1):

The particle「が」is used in a lot of contexts to explain a characteristic of something. In the song title, it is simply attaching a behavior to a subject, so, in a general sense:

```
*snow* --> "fall" [action]
```

The song title conveys: this *thing* (snow) does *thing* (fall). No additional or deeper meaning can be extracted of this sentence.

In the lyrics part, the story is totally different. When the author uses 「は」there, it is (in addition to stating the action that the subject is doing: *to fall*), giving you a notion of **sequential actions**, essentially: **the passing of time**. That nuance gives the sentence a deeper, sadder meaning:

```
Snow *keeps falling (and falling, ...)* and you still (don't/won't) come.
```

It could even be interpreted as "She'll never come back", but that's just a personal interpretation (I don't know the song / know the rest of the lyrics).