# How to respond to ポイントカードが宜しいですか。

Tags: expressions

When I am paying for my goods at a supermarket or *konbini*, the cashier always asks me that question. On dictionaries, the meaning of 宜しい is "fine / good" and it made me confused, "What is good about the point card?"

Then I assumed that they actually asked me if I have a point card. I knew that I can just say はい and show the cashier my point card if I have one. Well, I do not own one so I usually respond 「カードがない 。」 but the cashier often seems confused after hearing my answer.

Comment: I'd interpret it as something like "Everything is OK regarding your point card?"

Comment: @will Yes, it turns out that your interpretation is true.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Japanese よい/いい/よろしい sometimes means "... is not necessary" or "fine without ..."

> - コーヒーはいいです。 (Thank you but) I don't want coffee.
> - いや、いいです。 No thanks. / I don't need it. (e.g., to a salesperson)
> - その話はもういい。 That's enough!
> - 言い訳はよろしい。 Don't make excuses.

Therefore, "ポイントカード**は**よろしいですか?" means something like "You don't want to use a point card, right?" or "Are you okay without a point card?" I believe the cashier said は, not が. ポイントカード**が**よろしいですか would mean "Do you rather prefer a point card (over something else)?"

When you respond to it, はい or いいです means "I'm fine without it" or "I won't use one". (If はい worked in your case, I think the cashier guessed your intention from your gesture rather than your words.) If you want to use a point card, you can say いや, あります or 使います.

カード**が**ない is indeed very confusing because it sounds like "My card is missing!", i.e., you want to use a point card but just noticed you have lost it. Read [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010) for the reason. カード**は**ない at least works, although blunt.

Comment: Ahh I see.. I have made silly mistakes then, lol. About は or が thing, I am not sure. But I think you are right: the cashier says は. Thanks for the amazing answer!

Comment: How do I respond if I do have a card? 「良くないです」？

Comment: @Sweeper 良くないです/宜しくないです ("I am not fine") actually works, but it sounds a bit accusatory/sarcastic. People usually say 使います or あります, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with naruto. You can just say はい, いいです or 結構です. All of these mean "I don't need that."

> Well, I do not own one so I usually respond 「カードがない 。」 but the cashier often seems confused after hearing my answer.

I guess that's because カードがない is ambiguous and I imagine the cashier thought "did he lose his card? Or he left it in his home? Or he simply doesn't own one?" A cashier is a routine work so it's no wonder they are used to はい, いいです, 結構です but カードがない. You are not wrong.

Comment: Yeah.. Today I used はい、いいです and the cashier was not confused anymore, lol. Thanks!