# What is the purpose of the が particle in this sentence?

Tags: particle-が

友だちがきれいな花をくれました。

I have translated this as:
 Friend gave (me) beautiful flowers.

I did not understand the usage of が , couldn't we have used は ?
And in this case is my translation correct?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/18608 might be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons to use が instead of は here:

1. This 友だち has not been mentioned in the discourse yet. In other words, this sentence is "**A** friend of mine game me a flower" rather than "**The** friend game me a flower."
2. This *ga* is a neutral-description *ga*.

   - [Can someone explain me the use of は and が in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010)
   - [Why is this sentence ungrammatical? 「お寺が公園のとなりです。」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68923/5010])
   - [Why does 「電話は切れた」 sound more adversarial than 「電話が切れた」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38639/5010)

Saying 友だちはきれいな花をくれました is still grammatical, but the meaning would be a little different.