# difference when using は and が with てくれる structure

Tags: particles, particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

So, I think that I'm not alone when it comes to being confused about when は and が are supposed to be used, but here I would like to ask about a specific example

```
浅野君は（私に）かわいい手袋を編んでくれた
 x
浅野君が（私に）かわいい手袋を編んでくれた
```

Is there a difference in both phrases? As far as I know (please correct me if I'm wrong), は is used to talk about already mentioned topics, while が is used to talk about new topics.

Comment: The second sentence isn't necessarily wrong, it just depends on what you're trying to convey. The first sentence is simply stating a fact, whereas the second sentence adds some nuance, perhaps that you're really happy that Asano knitted a pair of gloves for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper noun like 浅野君 is usually considered always in the discourse (i.e., there is no "*an* 浅野君"), but there are times when you have to use が for such a noun.

This type of が used in the second sentence is called **neutral-description *ga***. It is used to report something as a *newly* observed event.

> #### [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010)
>
> Sentences of neutral description present an objectively observable action, existence, or temporary state **as a new event**.

On the other hand, は is used to describe a generic fact and to describe an event as a *known* fact.

In your case, 浅野君**は**手袋を編んでくれた is preferred when you're writing a diary or you're recalling this as a past event. 浅野君**が**手袋を編んでくれた must be used when you tell this news to your friend immediately after you received the gloves.

Lastly, This は/が distinction is not directly related to the ～てくれる construction.

Related:

- [Can someone explain me the use of は and が in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010)
- [Why does 「電話は切れた」 sound more adversarial than 「電話が切れた」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38639/5010)
- [Why is this sentence ungrammatical? 「お寺が公園のとなりです。」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68923/5010)