# In the sentence, "母がすしを作ります。", why do we use が instead of は?

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

My book sentence: 母がすしを作ります。

[image: img1]

I consulted another book, which states:

> The case particle *ga* can mark the subject of the sentence. However, when the subject noun is also treated as the topic of the sentence, being marked by *wa*, *ga* cannot be present. That is a part of the reason why the particle *wa* often wrongly gives the impression of being the subject marker.

As I continued reading, from what I've understood, the context is insufficient, there is none actually. In fact, I think that we can use either particle for the following reasons:

1. We can use が when we first introduce a item.
2. We can use は when when the item was previously introduced or is already known.

How do we apply the above to the sentence? We may consider two cases:

1. The speaker just told the listener that her mother will make sushi.
2. The listener already knows the speaker has a mother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can think 母 is always in "the universe of discourse", because when you say 母, it's determined; it almost certainly refers to your own mother. This means は is the ordinary particle choice. Usually, you should say 母はすしを作ります, replacing が with the topic-marker は.

However, が can be used in the following two cases:

- When exhaustive-が is intended.

  > 母がすしを作ります。
  > It's *my mother* who makes sushi.
  > <sub>(as a response to "Who makes sushi?")</sub>
- When neutral-description-が is intended.

  > 母がすしを作ります。
  > (I just noticed) my mother will make sushi!
  > <sub>(when you are told to report everything happening in your house)</sub>

I think your textbook will soon explain these special usages of が, but you can read several previous questions:

- [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010)
- [Can someone explain me the use of は and が in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010)
- [Why is this sentence ungrammatical? 「お寺が公園のとなりです。」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68923/5010)
- [Why does 「電話は切れた」 sound more adversarial than 「電話が切れた」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38639/5010)

Either way, if there is no previous context at all, 母がすしを作ります sounds unnatural and sudden. But textbooks sometimes need to show you this kind of "un-topicalized" sentence to explain how the Japanese sentence is structured.