# What is the difference when I swap が and は in this sentence

Tags: particle-は, particle-が, は-and-が

I want to know if my first translation of a sentence is wrong and more importantly **why**.

I'm using Duolingo as one of a couple tools for learning Japanese.
Today I got the sentence "The coffee here is delicious"
At first I translated it "ここ**が**コーヒー**は**美味しいです" In my head the super literal translation came out to "here **is the target location of** coffee **that is** delicious." Duolingo said it was wrong and that my が and は we're backwards.

I now know **は** marks the topic of the sentence and **が** marks the subject of the verb.

So the translation I gave I think is closer to "In reference to the coffee, here it's delicious"

Am I still interpreting the Japanese I wrote wrong?
Is this bad grammar or just weird sentence structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ここがコーヒーは美味しいです is a perfectly correct sentence, but it's nuanced. This is a correct sentence if you wanted to say "***Here*** is the place where coffee is delicious" or "It is ***this*** shop that offers delicious coffee". A sentence like this is natural only when someone asked you about the best café in the town or asked you to guide them there. This type of が is called exhaustive-listing が, which is a particle used to say "(this is) *the one*".

- [Why is this sentence ungrammatical? 「お寺が公園のとなりです。」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68923/5010)

However, for now, you have to translate "The coffee here is delicious", which is a plain sentence that does not emphasize the "here" part. You have to translate it plainly without emphasizing "here". A natural way of doing so in Japanese is to construct a so-called "double-subject" sentence. You can mark ここ with は, making it as the topic ("Here, ..."), and then say コーヒーが美味しい ("coffee is delicious"). I think you have seen typical double-subject sentences like 私は猫が好きです ("I like cats"), 彼は背が高いです ("He is tall") or ゾウは鼻が長いです ("Elephants have a long nose"). You need to follow the same pattern here.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough response. I got the contents right but the nuance wrong. ありがとうございます！