# 思います grammar including て-Form

Tags: syntax, phrases, sentence, grammar

I have question regarding the following sentence in English:

I also think that holidays are good and people need it.

At first I came up with this:

> 私も休日がよくて人はそれがいると思います。

But I am not sure whether this would be the better solution?

> 私も人は休日が要ってこれがよいと思います。

Is there a specific order or rule I can apply to this?

Comment: 私も means "I also" in the sense of "me too", not "in addition." So this sentence implies you're agreeing with what someone else said. Is that not the case?

Comment: yeah, it's just like a short confirmation/summary of what the pre-speaker said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer (or main) clause is just fine; 私も～と思います means "I also think that ～". But the inner clause (the opinion itself) has several errors.

1. First, you must use は instead of the first が, because "holidays are good" is a generic statement that is supposed to be always true. これがよい only means "this one is the better one (than the other one)".

   > 休日はよくて人はそれがいる
2. よい/いい is a [tricky adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57912/5010) which may mean the opposite of what you think. To avoid this, you should use もの ("thing") and say 休日はよいものだ (literally "Holidays are good things").

   > 休日はよいもので、人はそれがいる
3. 人はそれがいる is not 100% wrong in casual settings, but normally you need に before this は. This use of それ is a bit odd because それ usually refers to a specified singular object. You can repeat 休日, or omit it altogether because it can be inferred. 必要 fits better in a formal sentence.

   > 休日はよいもので、人には必要だ

All in all, you can say:

> - 私も、休日はよいもので、人には必要だと思います。
> - 私も、休日はよいもので、人間に必要なものだと思います。
> - 休日はよいものであり、人間は休日を必要としている、と私も考えます。

Comment: In the sentence "人には必要だ", what's the usage of に?

Comment: @古手梨花 I never thought about it seriously, but we do say 彼にはできる, 彼には分かる, 彼には夢がある and so on, so I think this is probably in the same vein...