# 日本語を勉強していて、楽しい？ meaning

Tags: て-form

日本語を勉強していて、楽しい？ (From Human Japanese Intermediate Ch. 24)

This is translated as "Studying Japanese, is it fun?" in the lesson which got me a bit confused. Can someone explain more about what the て-form here does for the sentence? Up until now in my studies, if I wanted to ask this, it would probably be something like 日本語を勉強するのは楽しい？ or 日本語を勉強することは楽しい？

I do know that the て-form can be used to link phrases like in  猫を助けて、家に帰ります where I'll help the cat and then go home, and this is the closest usage I can think of for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel the actual source of your confusion is the interpretation of this 楽しい. 楽しい in this context is closer to "are you having fun" rather than "is it fun". See [my previous answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66390/5010) for the two possible meanings of 楽しい. A literal translation is more like this:

> 日本語を勉強していて、楽しい？
>   Studying Japanese, are you having fun?
>   Are you having fun while you are studying Japanese?

The te-form before this comma is functioning like "while" or "by", but I hope you already know how it works ([this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38769/5010) is relevant). Note that the unmentioned topic is consistently "you" throughout this sentence. Of course, it is also perfectly fine to say "日本語を勉強するのは楽しい?".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the 楽しい part as you were pretty spot on with it being the source of my confusion!