# Does the が particle always mark the focus when marking the subject?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が

I recently read lots of articles/posts from the が particle usages and there is something which isn't clear for me. So the basic usage of the が is to mark the subject of the sentence. But in addition が can be used to mark the focus of the sentence and in this case it is an exhaustive listing or neutral description.

First I think the が particle always marks the subject and the focus at the same time, because lots of article doesn't state the opposite. But seems that’s not true. The [japanesewithanime.com](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/05/ga-particle.html#focus-marker) says the following:

> The ga が particle can mark a noun as having the focus in a **simple sentence**.

But what is the situation with the complex sentence? So after this I'm thinking lot and came the following conclusion:

**When the が subject marker is used in a simple sentence or in a main clause then it marks the focus too. However が subject marker doesn't mark the focus too in the subordinate clause. Am I right?**

So based on it the が is just a "plain" subject marker in the following example:

> 私 は　お母{かあ}さん が　作{つく}った　お菓子{かし} を　食{た}べました。

So what I want to know: is it possible the が is just a plain subject marker in the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The subject of a main clause is typically marked with は, so when が is used instead, it carries a nuance such as *exhaustive-listing* or *neutral-description*.

> お母さんは英語を勉強しています。
> My mother is studying English.
> <sup>(neutral; described as a known fact)</sup>
>
> お母さんが英語を勉強しています。
> It's *my mother* who is studying English.
> <sup>(nuanced: exhaustive-listing-ga)</sup>
>
> お母さんが英語を勉強しています。
> (I found/report) My mom is studying English.
> <sup>(nuanced: [neutral-description](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010)-ga)</sup>

On the other hand, the subject of a subordinary clause (including a relative clause) is marked with が by default, so it carries no extra nuance there. If は is used within a relative clause, that's probably a nuanced は known as contrastive-wa.

> 顔が美しい人
> a person whose face is beautiful
> <sup>(neutral)</sup>
>
> 顔は美しい人
> a person whose face, at least, is beautiful
> <sup>(nuanced: indicates this person has some fault)</sup>