# Is the use "ほしい” appropriate in these sentences?

Tags: grammar

Professor A asked you to go to his room.

> A先生があなたを先生の部屋に行ってほしいです。

Is it OK? I feel it is not quite natural.

Similarly, how to say "Professor A hopes you can concentrate on the XX research."

> A先生があなたをXX研究に集中してほしいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentences are not quite grammatical for the following reasons.

- To describe a third person's desire, you must use 欲しがる instead of 欲しい. See: [When to use 欲しがる instead of 欲しい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2524/5010)
- The person actually performing the action (aka *agent*) must be marked with に instead of を. あなた**を**欲しがっている in Japanese is acceptable only in sexual, headhunting or flesh-trading contexts.
- You perhaps want to use は instead of が in your second example because the desire of A先生 is probably not temporary in this case. See: [Can someone explain me the use of は and が in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010) and [Why does 「電話は切れた」 sound more adversarial than 「電話が切れた」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38639/5010)

After fixing them, you'll get:

> - A先生があなたに先生の部屋に行って欲しがっています。
> - A先生はあなたにXX研究に集中して欲しがっています。

Answer (score 1):

Although naruto covered the grammatical aspects, I disagree with his answer insofar as I don't think 欲しい/欲しがる would be used in these cases.

For your first sentence, my choice of phrasing would depend on whether it's important to explicitly mention the room. If it isn't, then a simple

> A先生があなたを呼んでいます。("Professor A is asking for you.")

If mentioning the room is important, then something along the lines of

> A先生は研究室へ行くようにとおっしゃっていました。("Professor A said you have to go to his office.")

(Adjusting the ◯◯室 as appropriate for the actual type of room; 部屋 is likely to be misinterpreted as the professor's apartment).

In your second example, I'd favour the てもらう construction:

> A先生はあなたにXX研究に集中してもらいたいとおっしゃっていました。("Professor A said he wants you to focus on (the) XX research.")

Obviously, this differs a lot from your initial attempts, but I think it's unlikely that 欲しい/欲しがる would be used in the situations presented in your sentences.

There are, of course, a number of possible ways to express the general idea, but the ones I present here are the ones I come across in the workplace on a regular basis (substituting an upper level manager for the professor).