# Meaning difference between 夜は明ける and 夜が明ける?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In [this song lyrics](https://genius.com/Given-yorugaakeru-lyrics), 夜が明ける is the name of the song, but until the end of the song 夜は明ける is used. This sounds like there is a distinct meaning difference between the two forms. I read about the difference between が and は, but I could not understand it in this concept.

ありがとうございます。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%e3%81%af-and-ga-%e3%81%8c

Comment: Also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38639/7810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

夜**が**明ける is so-called "a neutral description" or 現象文; basically it's a vivid description of the event this person is currently experiencing. On the other hand, 夜**は**明ける is a description of a fact which is "known" to the speaker. Therefore 夜が明ける is more like "(I'm seeing) this night is dawning", whereas 夜は明ける is more like "Nights (always) dawn".

See the following articles:

- [Can someone explain me the use of は and が in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010)
- [Why does 「電話は切れた」 sound more adversarial than 「電話が切れた」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38639/5010)

Answer (score 1):

夜が明ける describes how night is about to break in this moment. On the other hand, 夜は明ける argues with common sense that night is supposed to break.

Comment: i’m not sure what you mean by “argues with common sense.” that almost sounds like you’re saying that common sense would lead one to believe the sun will never rise. that’s just the opposite of common sense. could you clarify the distinction you’re trying to make here?

Comment: I think user4902 meant “argue with” in the sense of “argue using” not “argue against” here.